# Java 8 stream filter behaves strangely (does not filter)

Tags: java, java-stream

Anybody Please help me on this issue.
I'm using java 8 stream api filter method, and don't get what I expect.
Who can explain me, why this block of code doesn't work, say the first filter doesn't filter:

```
List<Participant> participants = participantRepository.findAllByConferenceId(conferenceId);
    participants
            .stream()
            .filter(participant -> partIdSet.contains(participant.getParticipantId()))
            .filter(participant -> !ParticipantStatusCode.DISCONNECTED.equals(participant.getStatusCode()))
            .forEach(p -> {
                p.setStatusCode(ParticipantStatusCode.DISCONNECTED);
                p.getActivity().forEach(activity -> activity.setEndDatetime(TimeUtils.getTime()));
            });
```

but in this way of using filter, it works properly

```
List<Participant> participants = participantRepository.findAllByConferenceId(conferenceId);
    participants = participants
            .stream()
            .filter(part -> partIdSet.contains(part.getParticipantId()))
            .filter(participant -> !ParticipantStatusCode.DISCONNECTED.equals(participant.getStatusCode()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    participants.forEach(p -> {
                p.setStatusCode(ParticipantStatusCode.DISCONNECTED);
                p.getActivity().forEach(activity -> activity.setEndDatetime(TimeUtils.getTime()));
            });
```

And Please, if you have any other solution, that could be nicer and readable, don't hasitate to suggest

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: In the first example, you do not collect the stream result.

Comment: Please be more specific than “this block of code doesn't work.”  What behavior were you expecting to see?  What did you see instead?

Comment: @Turing85 Could you finally tell me what is your desired format of giving a question. I just questioned and get  down votes and close votes, it 's nearly 20 minutes I am reading your specificaton, you just sent me, but cant find the point, where you mention the right way of posting a question.

Comment: I recommend taking the [tour], as well as taking a look at the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: P.S.: I cannot tell why people downvoted. I did not downvote.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are mutating the input of a consumer in both examples, which is not the intended way to use streams. Ideally you would want immutable participants and a way to create new participants and collecting them later:

```
List<Participant> processedParticipants = participants.stream()
        .filter(participant -> partIdSet.contains(participant.getParticipantId()))
        .filter(participant -> !ParticipantStatusCode.DISCONNECTED.equals(participant.getStatusCode()))
        .map(p -> new Participant(
                ParticipantStatusCode.DISCONNECTED,
                p.getActivity().stream()
                    .map(...)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```